# I have some difficulties calculate with mySQL commands that I want to do

Tags: mysql, sql

I made a calculation with below script but the result is different

```
select claim_by,
count(*) as total_response,
count(response_time>minute(response_time-30)) as total_target,
count(response_time>minute(response_time+30)) as total_untarget
from master_response
where claim_by = 'user'
GROUP BY claim_by
```

result : total_response = 42, total_target = 23, total_untarget = 19

for the result, total_target and total_untarget are different if I count manually
it should be total_target = 27 and total_untarget = 15

Comment: could you give some example data?

Comment: I bet the problem is in `>` and it should `>=`, you're missing results where `response_time = minute(response_time+/-30)`

Comment: Did you check for null values in `response_time` column? They may be causing this. Better yet, evaluate your expressions without grouping and aggregating to see which records don't match target and untarget. There could be an issue with using wrong operator as well.

Comment: `response_time>minute(response_time-30)` expression is too strange. What datatype `response_time` column have?

Comment: Or it could be `minute(response_time) +/- 30`

Comment: @Akina datatype is time

Comment: Please post the data that is being incorrectly classified

Comment: If so `minute(response_time-30)` may return NULL. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=892e5a0b2d36af9ebfb726ac6e35e4cf). Use `MINUTE(response_time - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)`.

Comment: And `response_time>minute(response_time-30)` is incorrect too - you cannot obtain the result which makes sense during compare TIME value of `response_time` and INTEGER value returned by `MINUTE()` function.

Comment: example data :
claim_by = user1
response_time = 0:07:03 and 0:46:34

Comment: claim_by response_time
user 0:07:03
user 0:27:06
user 0:08:07
user 1:28:19
user 0:02:01
user 0:46:34
user 0:58:51
user 0:16:44
user 2:02:38

Answer (score 0):

I would expect your two counts to return the *same* value.  If you want to count matches, use `sum()` instead of `count()`:

```
select claim_by,
       count(*) as total_response,
       sum(response_time > minute(response_time - 30)) as total_target,
       sum(response_time > minute(response_time + 30)) as total_untarget
from master_response
where claim_by = 'user'
group by claim_by;
```

`count()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  `sum()` adds the number of true values.

That said, you may want `<` for one of the comparisons.  I'm not sure which, but I might guess:

```
       sum(response_time < minute(response_time - 30)) as total_target,
       sum(response_time > minute(response_time + 30)) as total_untarget
```

It is also unclear why you are using the `minute` function.  So, perhaps you intend:

```
       sum(response_time < now() - interval 30 minute) as total_target,
       sum(response_time > now() + interval 30 minute) as total_untarget
```

Comment: sum(response_time < now() - interval 30 minute) as total_target,
sum(response_time > now() + interval 30 minute) as total_untarget
the result :total_response = 42, total_target = 42, total_untarget = 0

Comment: I want to get data on how much the total data obtained from time is less than 30 minutes and the total amount obtained from time more than 30 minutes of this user